# Suppressed Exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

In the book OCP Java SE 8 Programmer II by Kathy Sierra, on page 203 it states that:

"9. D is correct" wherein is

D. RuntimeException c with no suppressed exception

but when I try to run this code, the output has suppressed exception of RuntimeException "a" and a main exception of IOException. What am I missing?

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Animals {
    class Lamb implements Closeable {
        public void close() {
            throw new RuntimeException("a");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Animals().run();
    }
    public void run() {
        try (Lamb l = new Lamb();) {
            throw new IOException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("c");
        }
    }
}
```

Adding this code in the catch block will show suppressed exception and IOException

```
    System.out.println("catch main: " + e);
    for (Throwable t : e.getSuppressed()) {
        System.out.println("catch suppressed " + t);
    }
```

Comment: "In the book OCP Java SE 8 Programmer II by Kathy Sierra, on page 203 it states that:" please don't assume we have access to this resource. Put as much information in the question as we need to understand (and leave out information we don't need).

Comment: "the output has suppressed exception of RuntimeException "a" and a main exception of IOException" what leads you to this conclusion? https://ideone.com/ajduBr looks like a RuntimeException, with no suppressed exception, to me

Comment: "the output has suppressed exception of RuntimeException "a" and a main exception of IOException" No it doesn't. Can you show what the textual output is exactly?

Comment: add this             System.out.println("catch main: " + e);
            for (Throwable t : e.getSuppressed()) {
                System.out.println("catch suppressed " + t);
            } to the catch and it will show exception

Comment: What question is "D is correct" answering? The question probably isn't asking about what exception has been caught by the `catch` block. So printing things in the `catch` block is not relevant at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the exception thrown by the `close` was suppressed by the one at the end of the try. You can observe this by examining the exception catched:

```
public void run() {
    try (Lamb l = new Lamb();) {
        throw new IOException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("catched "+e);
        for (var ex: e.getSuppressed())
            System.out.println("suppressed "+ex);
        throw new RuntimeException("c");
    }
}
```

Whose execution leads to:

```
catched java.io.IOException
suppressed java.lang.RuntimeException: a
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: c
    at Animals.run(Animals.java:20)
    at Animals.main(Animals.java:11)
```

The tutorial (see [Try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)) says:

> **Suppressed Exceptions**
>
> An exception can be thrown from the block of code associated with the
> try-with-resources statement. [...] If an exception is thrown from the try block
> and one or more exceptions are thrown from the try-with-resources
> statement, then those exceptions thrown from the try-with-resources
> statement are suppressed, and the exception thrown by the block is the
> one that is thrown [...]. You can
> retrieve these suppressed exceptions by calling the
> Throwable.getSuppressed method from the exception thrown by the try
> block.

But the `Runtime` thrown from the catch has no suppressed exception associated to it.

Comment: Have you read the book? Why do you think the authors thought otherwise?

Comment: But the statement D is correct, in the main there is no suppressed exception. The suppression occurs only inside the try-with-ressource.

Answer (score 0):

The question is : "Which exceptions will the code throw?", this means what exceptions will reach to main function (and even to command line):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

so if you want to verify which answer is correct, you should put:

```
new Animals().run();
```

into `try {} catch {}` and read exception type and suppressed exceptions there. You will see then that its indeed of RuntimeException type with "c", and no suppressed exceptions.